# Add a Wiki page for the "compounds" tag, or replace it with another tag

Tags: feature-request, retagging, tag-wiki

[compounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compounds) is without Wiki page. It should be good if the tag would have it, as the tag seems used for different purposes.

**Edit:** I just noticed there is also the [compound-sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compound-sentences) tag. Do the tags have the same meaning, or are they used in totally different questions?
If there other tags that can replace [compounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compounds), then it should be removed, as @waiwai933 suggests, or made a synonym for another tag, as suggested by @RedDwight in another question.

Comment: A great majority of our tags need Wiki pages. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bigger problem inherently here—there are both [compound-sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compound-sentences) and [compound-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compound-words) (although we haven't used that tag on E.SE). We should probably retag each of the questions to the right tag, and then have [compounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compounds) added to the blacklist.

I've submitted a suggested edit for [compound-sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compound-sentences).

Quick draft for [compound-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compound-words):

> A compound word is a word that has two or more word stems. They can be classified either semantically or formally, and both classifications are described below:
>
> **Semantic classifications**:
>
> - Endocentric—where the compound word's first stem marks a special type of the second stem (e.g. *dark* + *room*)
> - Exocentric— *? (I don't like the Wikipedia definition and I can't come up with a good one myself)*
> - Copulative—where the compound word's stems are the sum of the two stems (e.g. *sleep* + *walk*)
> - Appositional—where the two stems make up different facets of a role (e.g. *maid* + *servant*)
>
> Compound words can also be classified **formally**, where there exist *noun-noun compounds*, *verb-noun compounds*, *verb-verb compounds*, and *compound adpositions*. The derivations of the classifications is easily understood except the fourth, which is made up with a preposition and a noun.
>
> <sub>Derived from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)#Compound_adpositions), licensed under CC-BY-SA</sub>

[MSO question about using WP articles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000/) (for those of you that are curious).

Comment: I will create a feature request for blacklisting "compounds."

Comment: @kiam At this point, it would be pointless. We have to retag all the questions first.